# How to remove trailing characters in one line

Tags: perl, sed

I have file with patterns as shown:

```
a0
b00
c000
d0000000
e00
f00
```

How to write a perl oneliner or sed command to obtain output as:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

My trial:

```
sed -i 's/0*$//g' filename.txt
```

Comment: i don't c any issue with your command.

Comment: If your command is failing, I'm guessing the problem lies elsewhere.  Does your file contain DOS line endings? See if converting it with `dos2unix` would help.

Comment: What must be the result for `abc000`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/(.).*/\1/' File
```

Only print the first character from each line.

Comment: Perhaps the global flag `g` is not needed in a match that can only match once at most.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `perl` equivalent (inplace replacement):

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.).*$/$1/' file
```

And if you are curious an `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{print $1}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

very likely there are trailing spaces in your lines, give this sed oneliner a try:

```
sed 's/0*\s*$//' file
```

Note that the `g` flag is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One way using perl:

```
perl -F"" -alne 'print $F[0]' file
```